# Drill Through By Mapping Fields

Tags: powerbi, dax

Say I have Page 'A' and I want to drill through to Page 'B'. Ordinarily I would set up the drill through by specifying the field in page B that "joins" the same field from page A.

I want to do something slightly different. I would like to somehow specify that the **User Name** column from a table on page A should be used to filter the **Manager Name** field, from the same table, in page B.

For example, assume on page A, the current User Name is John Smith. On page B I would like the value of John Smith to be used to filter the Manager Name field from the same table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and presentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting prompt. I think one way to do this is to have your `[User Name]` and `[Manager Name]` fields in a table in your model with ONLY an inactive relationship on the `[Manager Name]`. Then, when you filter on the `[User Name]`, you would use DAX calculations that look something like this:

```
YourMeasure =
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( 'NewTable'[User Name] ) = TRUE (),
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE (
            [ExistingMeasure],
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'NewTable', [Manager Name] ),
            USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Table1'[Manager Name], 'NewTable'[Manager Name] )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

The main consideration here is that you'd have to do this for each measure you want to display on Page B.